# param error key not found after adding validate_number

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Everything worked before adding:

|> validate_number(:age, greater_than: 0, message: "error")

I wanted this to validate the form.
I have no idea why the parameter isn't found anymore it worked perfectly before and changing the param manually to ["Admin", "Manager", "User"] in the html.eex works aswell.

context

```
 defmodule Webshop.UserContext.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Webshop.ItemContext.Item
  alias Webshop.ReviewContext.Review

  @acceptable_roles ["Admin", "Manager", "User"]
 

  schema "users" do
    field :age, :integer
    field :name, :string
    field :tel, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :hashed_password, :string
    field :role, :string, default: "User"

    has_many :reviews, Review #I'm new!

    many_to_many :items, Item, join_through: "users_items", join_keys: [user_id: :id, item_id: :id] # I'm new!

    timestamps()
  end

  def get_acceptable_roles, do: @acceptable_roles

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :age, :tel, :password, :role])
    |> validate_required([:name, :age,:tel,:password,:role])
    |> validate_number(:age, greater_than: 0, message: "error")
    |> validate_inclusion(:role, @acceptable_roles)
    |> put_password_hash()
    
  end

  defp put_password_hash(
         %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} = changeset
       ) do
    change(changeset, hashed_password: Argon2.hash_pwd_salt(password))
  end

  defp put_password_hash(changeset), do: changeset
end
```

heex file

```
<.form let={f} for={@changeset} action={@action}>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= label f, :name %>
  <%= text_input f, :name %>
  <%= error_tag f, :name %>

  <%= label f, :age %>
  <%= number_input f, :age %>
  <%= error_tag f, :age %>

  <%= label f, :tel %>
  <%= telephone_input f, :tel %>
  <%= error_tag f, :tel %>

  <%= label f, :password %>
  <%= text_input f, :password %>
  <%= error_tag f, :password %>

  <%= label f, :role %>
  <%= select f, :role, @acceptable_roles %>
  <%= error_tag f, :role %>


  <div>
    <%= submit "Save" %>
  </div>
</.form>
```

the error:

```
key :acceptable_roles not found in: 
%{
action: "/users", 
changeset: #Ecto.Changeset<
  action: :insert, 
  changes: %{
    age: -10, 
    name: "10", 
    password: "10", 
    tel: "10"
  }, 
  errors: [
    age: {"kanker", [validation: :number, kind: :greater_than, number: 0]}], data: #Webshop.UserContext.User<>, valid?: false>, 
conn: %Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, 
assigns: %{changeset: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{age: -10, name: "10", password: "10", tel: "10"}, 
errors: [age: {"kanker", [validation: :number, kind: :greater_than, number: 0]}], 
data: #Webshop.UserContext.User<>, valid?: false>, 
layout: {WebshopWeb.LayoutView, "app.html"}}, 
body_params: %{
  "_csrf_token" => "J3VmIAwcWwEPCQ5vODooAgsFbE0mCCATnC_riQ30l1V-humzSvUtaQeC", 
  "user" => %{"age" => "-10", "name" => "10", "password" => "10", "role" => "User", "tel" => "10"}}, 
cookies: %{"Idea-7bc9e2c7" => "25312f04-5f8b-41d4-ae61-250f6f27a0df", "_webshop_web_key" => "SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYSTY5UmVNaDFjOFhCUE9FeFhzOTlHWUVQ.U6Dy-Ge8XworfsYVuZpM5-iWjgAUGB4OQMY_QHNBm10", 
"locale" => "en"}, 
halted: false, 
host: "localhost", 
method: "POST", 
owner: #PID<0.776.0>, 
params: %{"_csrf_token" => "J3VmIAwcWwEPCQ5vODooAgsFbE0mCCATnC_riQ30l1V-humzSvUtaQeC", 
"user" => %{"age" => "-10", "name" => "10", "password" => "10", "role" => "User", "tel" => "10"}}, 
path_info: ["users"], path_params: %{}, port: 4000, 
private: %{WebshopWeb.Router => {[], %{Plug.Swoosh.MailboxPreview => ["mailbox"]}}, :before_send => [#Function<0.16477574/1 in Plug.CSRFProtection.call/2>, #Function<2.17183421/1 in Phoenix.Controller.fetch_flash/2>, #Function<0.77458138/1 in Plug.Session.before_send/2>, #Function<0.23023616/1 in Plug.Telemetry.call/2>, #Function<1.25036529/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/3>], :guardian_error_handler => WebshopWeb.ErrorHandler, :guardian_module => WebshopWeb.Guardian, :phoenix_action => :create, :phoenix_controller => WebshopWeb.UserController, :phoenix_endpoint => WebshopWeb.Endpoint, :phoenix_flash => %{}, :phoenix_format => "html", :phoenix_layout => {WebshopWeb.LayoutView, :app}, :phoenix_request_logger => {"request_logger", "request_logger"}, :phoenix_root_layout => {WebshopWeb.LayoutView, :root}, :phoenix_router => WebshopWeb.Router, :phoenix_template => "new.html", :phoenix_view => WebshopWeb.UserView, :plug_session => %{"_csrf_token" => "I69ReMh1c8XBPOExXs99GYEP"}, :plug_session_fetch => :done}, query_params: %{}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, req_cookies: %{"Idea-7bc9e2c7" => "25312f04-5f8b-41d4-ae61-250f6f27a0df", "_webshop_web_key" => "SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYSTY5UmVNaDFjOFhCUE9FeFhzOTlHWUVQ.U6Dy-Ge8XworfsYVuZpM5-iWjgAUGB4OQMY_QHNBm10", "locale" => "en"}, req_headers: [{"accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"}, {"accept-language", "nl,ja;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6"}, {"cache-control", "max-age=0"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}, {"content-length", "163"}, {"content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, {"cookie", "Idea-7bc9e2c7=25312f04-5f8b-41d4-ae61-250f6f27a0df; locale=en; _webshop_web_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYSTY5UmVNaDFjOFhCUE9FeFhzOTlHWUVQ.U6Dy-Ge8XworfsYVuZpM5-iWjgAUGB4OQMY_QHNBm10"}, {"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"origin", "http://localhost:4000"}, {"referer", "http://localhost:4000/users/new"}, {"sec-ch-ua", "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"101\""}, {"sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0"}, {"sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\""}, {"sec-fetch-dest", "document"}, {"sec-fetch-mode", "navigate"}, {"sec-fetch-site", "same-origin"}, {"sec-fetch-user", "?1"}, {"upgrade-insecure-requests", "1"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36"}], request_path: "/users", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{"locale" => %{max_age: 31536000, value: "en"}}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, {"x-request-id", "Fu-u6fQSIUO7CEoAAATC"}, {"x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"}, {"x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"}, {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"}, {"x-download-options", "noopen"}, {"x-permitted-cross-domain-policies", "none"}, {"cross-origin-window-policy", "deny"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: :..., state: :unset, status: nil}}
```

Comment: What you receive is `"user" => %{"age" => "-10", "name" => "10",…`, it’s impossible to tell why without seeing your inputs.

Comment: My inputs are 10 for everything except for age = -10 and role = user (it was just a test input for the age validation)

Comment: Why do you expect `-10` to pass validation `validate_number(:age, greater_than: 0, message: "error")`??

Comment: I don't but I expect it to give an error message underneath the label.

Comment: There seems to be something you aren't showing us. The error at the top of your response is that the key :acceptable_roles is not found. There is no reference in your code to that key. Have a look for that key in your full code and fix that. It's likely preventing you from actually making use of the changeset errors for display.